# Excel VBA assign values in Array and Plot in bar chart

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, plot

I can select several id (numbers) via a list box. The chosen id is taken into account in the For- loop.

Each id contains a value in its line in the sheet Messübersicht, which I determine using the variable PmWERT

Question:

In the next step, I would like to save all determined PmWERT as a new variable. Then plot them as a barchart. How can I create a vector or something like that which save all the PmWERT values behind each other? And how can I plot the values as a barchart then?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Auswerten_Click()

Dim Diagramm As Shape
lastRow = Sheets("Messübersicht").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

Dim text As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox_MessID.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox_MessID.Selected(i) Then
        text = text & Me.ListBox_MessID.List(i) & vbNewLine
        Set foundRng = Sheets("Messübersicht").Range("B:B").Find(Me.ListBox_MessID.List(i))
        MsgBox foundRng.Address
        PMWERT = Sheets("Messübersicht").Cells(foundRng.Row, foundRng.Column + 22).Value
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a chart, add a newSeries to the chart, and assign to .xValues and .Values a Range or, perhaps, an array (of perhaps Double or Integer):

```
    Sub testchart()
    Dim yList() As Double
    ReDim yList(3) ' say there are 4 values
    yList(0) = 6.1
    yList(1) = 8
    yList(2) = 4.3
    yList(3) = 2
    
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(a, b, 900, 300) ' Left, Top, Width, Height
        With .Chart
            .ChartType = xlBarClustered
            ' need to add the series before you can assign the values/xvalues
            ' calling the "NewSeries" method add one series each time you call it.
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            ' now that the series is added, you may assign (not set) the values/xvalues
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A1:A4") ' it can be a Range or an array
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = yList ' it can be a Range or an array
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is it not easier to save first all the PmWERT values?

Comment: and after saving like a vector or something like that you can plot the vector?

Comment: Yes, you may assign the PmWERT values to cells, say Range("B1:B4") if there are 4 values, and then assign the Range to .SeriesColletion(1).Values = Range("B1:B4")